# About Equicontinuous and Boundedness

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Let $X$ be a TVS and $X'$ denotes the space of all continuous linear functionals on $X$. Let us denote the $weak^*$-topology on $X'$ by $\sigma(X',X).$

**My question is this.** Why does every equicontinuous subset $M$ of $X'$ is bounded with respect to $\sigma(X',X)?$

So far, I can show that if $M$ is an equicontinuous subset of $X'$ then $M\subseteq V^o$ for some open neighborhood of $0$ in $X$. Here, $V^o$ refers to the *polar set* of $V$. I don't have any idea on how to proceed...In fact I cannot imagine how the basic elements look like in $X'$ (in terms of polar sets, at least.) Thanks in advance.

Comment: What definition of equicontinuity do you use here?

Comment: $W'$ is equicontinuous at $c\in X$ iff for every $\epsilon >0$ we can find an open set $V$ in $X$ that contains $0\in X$ such that for any $w'\in W'$,$$x-c \Rightarrow |w'(x)-w'(c)|<\epsilon$$ $W'$ is equicontinuous iff it is equicontinuous at every point of $X$.

Comment: It should be $x-c\in V$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have $M \subset V^\circ =\{ S\in X'; |S(v)| \leq 1 \forall v\in V\}$. Fix $x\in X$. You need to show the existence of a constant $c>0$ with $$ |S(x)| <= c \operatorname{ for all }S\in M.$$
But as $V$ is absorbing, $cx\in V$ for some $c>0$, so $|S(cx)| \leq 1$ for all $S\in M$. Hence you can conclude.

Comment: @juniven A set is bounded in a locally convex space, iff it is bounded by every seminorm inducing the topology. Try to apply this.

Comment: You are absolute right. I got the idea of your proof. Thank you very much.